# Unable to find variable inside *ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My `CoreComponent` tells my `NotificationsService` to show a new notification and passes an html string in the `content` property:

```
export class CoreComponent {

  constructor(private _notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
    this._notificationsService.show({content: '<h1 (click)="close()">hej hej</h1>'});
  }
}
```

Then my `NotificationsComponent` comes into play after the `NotificationsService` have forwarded the notification to the component, this component must render a fake component so all bindings and directives set on the html in `content` will work:

```
export class NotificationsComponent {
  public notifications: string[] = [];

  constructor(private _notificationsService: NotificationsService, dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {

    _notificationsService.newNotification$.subscribe(
      notification => {

        this.notifications.push(notification);

        if (notification.content) {

          dcl.loadIntoLocation(toComponent(notification.content, []), elementRef, 'content');

          function toComponent(template, directives = []) {

            @Component({
              selector: 'custom-content',
              template: template,
              directives: directives
            })

            class FakeComponent {}

            return FakeComponent;
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Then it renders a notification with an `*ngFor` loop:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#notification of notifications">
      <div #content></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem though is that it can't find the `#content` variable for some reason, it just throws an `Uncaught Could not find variable content`. My guess is because it's inside a loop, but I really don't know why if that is the case.

How can I render this fake component into the notifications template (preferably before pushing `notification` into `public notifications` so the component is actually there from the start when showing a new notification)?

**EDIT:** I found out that without the `*ngFor` my code works, but there is something about the loop that is causing issues here. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you generate several elements with the `#content` template variable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer But if that's the case why doesn't it render 1 element and any elements added after that throws an error? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are right, it should work. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6920

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Also tried using ngOnInit but yields the same result, it seems like it's trying to render the fake component before the template has rendered in some way.

Comment: I don't see any reason for using `*ngFor`, I think you could accomplish the result you want with just `<div #content></div>`

Comment: @Abdulrahman That will only allow one notification at a time unfortunately, which is not the end result I desire.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Interestingly enough it works if I remove the *ngFor, but like I said, not the result I wish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It works without the *ngFor, any idea why?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I don't know why the loop causes the problem.

Comment: [check this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EqHZiZ3s2pRb7U5hmkEg?p=preview), it's working. What i think is happening is that when you call `loadIntoLocation` the `#content` is not there yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work around the `ngFor` issue you could create a wrapper element that does the actual `dcl.loadIntoLocation()`

This wrapper component is added for each `notification` and gets the comonent passed that it then adds inside itself.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dcl-wrapper',
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class DclWrapper {
  constructor(private containerRef:ViewContainerRef, private dcl:DynamicComponentLoader) {}
  @Input() component;

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      throw 'currently changing type after the component was added is not supported'
    }
    this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(this.component, this.containerRef).then((cmpRef) => {
      this.cmpRef = cmpRef;
    });
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'core-comp',
  directives: [DclWrapper],
  template: `
  <h2>Tabs</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let notification of notifications">
    <dcl-wrapper [component]="notification"></dcl-wrapper>
  </div>
`
})
export class NotificationsComponent {
  public notifications: string[] = [];
  ...
}
```

Like also explained in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: What does `this.cmpRef = cmpRef` actually do? Like I know what it does but why do I need it?

Comment: This is to store the reference to the created component, in order to be able to remove it with `this.cmpRef.dispose()` (if I remember the method name correctly).

Comment: Hmm ok. Well it does solve the issue that I had so I'll accept the answer. Thanks :)